# How to integrate pre-compiled binaries into AOSP Android build?

Tags: android, android-source, ninja, ril

I have to modify my AOSP build so that it includes the following pre-compiled (arm64) binaries and library.

```
/system/bin/chat
/system/etc/ppp/ip-up
/system/etc/ppp/ip-down
/vendor/lib/libreference-ril.so
```

Where can I put these files in AOSP so that they end up in their proper locations?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the following SOONG commands: `cc_prebuilt_binary`, `prebuilt_etc` and `cc_prebuilt_library_shared`.

Examples of theirs usage can be easily found in AOSP tree, e.g. for `cc_prebuilt_binary`:

```
grep -irn cc_prebuilt_binary --include=Android.bp
...
system/core/logcat/Android.bp:54:cc_prebuilt_binary {
...
```

From `system/core/logcat/Android.bp`:

```
cc_prebuilt_binary {
    name: "logpersist.start",
    srcs: ["logpersist"],
    init_rc: ["logcatd.rc"],
    required: ["logcatd"],
    symlinks: [
        "logpersist.stop",
        "logpersist.cat",
    ],
    strip: {
        none: true,
    },
}
```

So, add your `Android.bp` with mentioned implemented commands and put it for example in `/vendor/my/Android.bp` (along with all prebuilt stuff) and then build AOSP.

Link to SOONG commands: https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/7079722/linux/latest/view/soong_build.html